# Can't access EC2 on domain name, just on IP. Cname is correct, and can route this domain to lightsail server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, domain, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

Thanks for taking the time. I have ported a lightsail instance over to EC2 and am running a t.2 larger server. I am running a wordpress site and the homepage is just a blank white page.

I have assigned the ec2 an eleastic IP and can access the wordpress server at this IP 52.27.6.201
But the domain, [www.showstream.io](http://www.showstream.io) is not available. Anyone have any ideas?

I can point the domain at the lightsail instance and it works no problem.

[route53 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciX3T.png)

Comment: `curl -I http://www.showstream.io/` works. `curl -I https://www.showstream.io/` times out for me. This indicates it's not a DNS or AWS issue, but more likely a configuration issue on the server.

Comment: Have you checked the basics like security groups for your instance?

Comment: Also, you HTTP page comes back as a 302 redirect to HTTPS for me. But it is responding. So I would bet that you haven't opened port 443 in your security group.

Comment: @shearn89 Thanks! it was the 443 port in security group. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Some quick debugging on the command line showed:

1. DNS resolves
2. HTTP queries work and come back with a 302 redirect to HTTPS
3. HTTPS times out.

My guess in the comments was that port 443 wasn't open in the security groups, so HTTPS traffic was blocked.